# Authentication error in trunking between two asterisk

Tags: asterisk

i'm creating a connection between two asterisk servers. I want only make calls from right side server to left side server, but i receive an authentication error. I can´t find the problem.

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3nGV.png)

[SIP CONF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riYVT.png)

[EXTENSIONS CONF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5EXw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you just specified the username but didn't provide the password defined in the [immtrunk] section.